# LSI HostRAID 2008 - Can't Create RAID 10 With More Than 10 Drives

Tags: raid10, lsi

I've got a Quanta Stratos server with an LSI HostRaid 2008 controller. I've got 24 SAS drives in it. No matter what I do I cannot get configure RAID 10 across all 24 drives. I've no experience with LSI controllers, I've only ever used PERC and I've always been able to generate volumes across all the drives in the server.

I've tried to create two separate RAID 10 volumes. I can create one with 10 drives, but when I try to create the second, I can only select 5.

Anything to point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I assume it depends on firmware. Some PERC are also based on LSI 2008 chip. I've found guide for SuperMicro MegaRaid LSI 2008 and according it only 8 drives are supported in RAID10 :)  https://www.supermicro.com/manuals/other/LSI_2008_SAS_MegaRAID_Configuration_Utility_LSI_2008_Controller.pdf

Comment: Yeah, I found that same guid too. It let me do it with 10. But why in the hell would they make a server that holds 25 drives if you can't use them all in the RAID you need...

Comment: Do you know the exact model of controller (LSI 2008 is a chip only, which can be used in different configurations)?

Comment: Here some controllers based on LSI 2008 - https://www.servethehome.com/lsi-sas-2008-raid-controller-hba-information/

Comment: In all honesty, just because I'm exhausted with this project - unless someone has some kind of "here, try this" - I'm probably going to just stick with what I know and through a PERC H800 in there. Set the thing up, and never look at that damn box again.

Comment: @batistuta09, I'll have to double check, but I believe it's a Quanta SAS 2008 Mezz card. https://www.hyperscalers.com/image/catalog/downloads/QCT%20Mezzanine%20Card%20Portfolio-v1.2.pdf